# Undefined index error presented when following Lynda.com's tut Beyond the Basics with Kevin Skoglund

Tags: php

I continue to get the following notice when I load this page.:

> (!)Notice:  Undefined index: clear

I'd appreciate any assistance in clearing this notice.

```
<?php require_once("../../includes/initialize.php"); ?>
<?php if (!$session->is_logged_in()) { redirect_to("login.php"); } ?>
<?php

  $logfile = SITE_ROOT.DS.'logs'.DS.'log.txt';

  if($_GET['clear'] == 'true') {
        file_put_contents($logfile, '');
      // Add the first log entry
      log_action('Logs Cleared', "by User ID {$session->user_id}");
    // redirect to this same page so that the URL won't 
    // have "clear=true" anymore
    redirect_to('logfile.php');
  }
?>

<h2>Log File</h2>

<p><a href="logfile.php?clear=true">Clear log file</a><p>
```

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['clear']) && $_GET['clear'] == 'true')` -- Also, this will probably be closed as duplicate quite soon.  Probably even downvoted a few times.  You might want to search the site first before asking very obvious questions.

Comment: I appreciate your prompt response along with providing the correct code.  Please note that I did search on "Undefined Index", but still found the postings not as helpful as what you provided in your response.  Thank you.